# How to debug a script that will kill by system when await multi Promise?

Tags: sockets, async-await, promise, raku

**Answer** ["the script used too much memory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71437228/how-to-debug-a-script-that-will-kill-by-system-when-await-multi-promise#comment126309794_71437228).

---

I start a few `start` to read text file line by line, and convert the text to blob, then send it to socket:

```
    use experimental :pack;

    sub heart-msg(Str $msg, Str $device-id --> Blob) {
        my $heart-msg = $msg.substr(0, $msg.chars - 8);
        my $header-buf = pack("H*", $heart-msg);
        my $device-id-buf = pack("L*", $device-id);

        $header-buf ~ $device-id-buf
    }

    sub deal-message(Str $msg, Str $device-id --> Blob) {
        my $now    = DateTime.now();
        my $year   = $now.year;
        my $month  = $now.month;
        my $day    = $now.day;
        my $hour   = $now.hour;
        my $minute = $now.minute;
        my $second = $now.second.Int;
        my $check-number = 0;

        my $head-msg         = $msg.substr(0,4);
        my $device-id-length = $msg.substr(4,2);
        my $pf-code          = $msg.substr(14, 2);
        my $msg-length       = $msg.substr(16, 4);
        my $rel-time         = $msg.substr(20, 4);
        my $end-msg          = $msg.substr(38, $msg.chars - 38 - 2);

        my $head-msg-buf      = pack("H*", $head-msg);
        my $device-id-len-buf = pack("H*", $device-id-length);
        my $device-id-buf     = pack("L*", $device-id);
        my $pf-code-buf       = pack("H*", $pf-code);
        my $msg-length-buf    = pack("H*", $msg-length);
        my $rel-time-buf      = pack("H*", $rel-time);
        my $year-buf          = pack("S*", $year);
        my $month-buf         = pack("C*", $month);
        my $day-buf           = pack("C*", $day);
        my $hour-buf          = pack("C*", $hour);
        my $minute-buf        = pack("C*", $minute);
        my $second-buf        = pack("C*", $second);
        my $end-msg-buf       = pack("H*", $end-msg);

        my @bufs = [$device-id-len-buf, $device-id-buf, $pf-code-buf, $msg-length-buf,
        $rel-time-buf, $year-buf, $month-buf, $day-buf, $hour-buf, $minute-buf, $second-buf,
        $end-msg-buf];

        for @bufs -> $byte {
            my $byte_sum = [+] $byte.contents;
            $check-number += $byte_sum;
        }

        $check-number = $check-number % 256;
        my $checked-msg-buf = pack("C*", $check-number);

        [~] $head-msg-buf, |@bufs, $checked-msg-buf
    }


    sub deal-data(Str $msg, Str $device-id --> Blob) {
        my $header = $msg.substr(0, 4);
        given $header {
            when '6868' {
                return deal-message($msg, $device-id);
            }
            when '7468' {
                return heart-msg($msg, $device-id);
            }
            default { return Buf.new }
        }
    }


sub MAIN(
         :$host = '10.0.0.77',
         Int() :$port = 4444,
         Rat() :$interval = 0.001,
         :$file = 'data.txt',
         Int() :$device-num = 169) {
    my $conn = IO::Socket::INET.new(:$host, :$port);
    my @devices = "modelId.txt".IO.lines;

    my @promises = gather for @devices[159..$device-num] -> $device-id {
        take start {
            my $f = lazy $file.IO.lines;
            my $iterator = $f.iterator;

            react {
                whenever Supply.interval($interval) {
                    try {
                        my $line := $iterator.pull-one;

                        if $line =:= IterationEnd {
                            done;
                        } else {
                            my $blob = deal-data($line.chomp.split(/\s+/).tail, $device-id.Str);
                            #say $blob;
                            $conn.write($blob);
                        }
                    }

                    QUIT {
                        $conn.close;
                        say 'connecting closed';
                        default {
                            say .^name, '→ ', .Str;
                            say "handled in line $?LINE";
                        }
                    }
                    LAST {
                        say "Connection closed";
                        done;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    await @promises;
}
```

When running on CentOS 7.4(12 core, 32G RAM), after a few seconds, my script was killed by system. When running on Win11(12 core, 16G RAM), it's OK.

So how to debug this script?

[image]

Comment: OOC, why are you using `Supply.interval` instead of [`IO.watch`](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Path#method_watch) ?

Comment: I want to control the speed of blob that sending to socket.

Comment: If that is so, why not just do `for $file.IO.lines { sleep 0.001; .send }` ?

Comment: Off the top of my (slightly rusty) head: Why wouldn't this work: `take start react whenever $file.IO.lines.Supply.throttle(1, 0.001) {...}`

Comment: @BradGilbert Have you seen niner's comment ["one must not use `gather`/`take` to collect results from `react`/`whenever`"](https://github.com/Raku/doc/issues/4041)? It seems more than plausible to me that your code suggestion is immune to the missing `take` control exception handler problem niner is talking about, because your `take` is *outside* the `react`/`whenever`. But I'm also pretty unsure about how things play out with Raku's use of continuations and threads so can imagine I'm wrong. If you're not already ahead of the game on this, maybe check out the issues niner has opened.

Comment: thanks everyone, I find out the script used too much memory, and killed by system.

Comment: @raiph Actually I haven't been watching Raku stuff that closely recently as my main computer has been down. I also only did one simplification. I would have probably done more if I weren't typing on a phone.

Comment: @BradGilbert Ah, OK. Thanks for commenting. Sorry to hear about the computer. I know how that can suck; I've only just recently mostly recovered from my main computer turning into a brick.