# Does DBIish Oracle driver support multi-threading, after all?

Tags: raku

The documentation for `DBIish` states that:

> Since early 2021 I've successfully implemented my Raku solution for
> using as many as Eight(8) threads all connected to Oracle performing
> simultaneous Reads and writes. As with Perl-5 the number one
> requirement is to ensure each thread creates is own connection handle
> with Oracle.

Following this rule I implemented some basic pooling where a thread requests for connection handle and get it when it's available. The pool gets filled with connection handles up to some pre-set limit.

There are also per-connection caches of the most used prepared statement handles.

Things work well with pool size of 1. I.e., basically no multi-threading. But as soon as the size is set to 2 I get `terminated by signal SIGKILL (Forced quit)` message after some 20-30 writes to the database.

What beats me is that receiving `SIGSEGV` or alike would be more anticipated. But `SIGKILL`? As if something kills my process externally?

**UPD** All this is on Linux. Linux Mint, for the sake of clarity.

Comment: What system? ["When running on Win11(12 core, 16G RAM), it's OK. When running on CentOS 7.4(12 core, 32G RAM), after a few seconds, my script was killed by system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71437228/how-to-debug-a-script-that-will-kill-by-system-when-await-multi-promise) may be unrelated, but the importance of specifying system details for a Q like this cannot be overstated imo, even if it turns out they're not relevant.

Comment: Makes sense, for sure. Updated the question.